# Loop exiting early when making Linux system calls

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, system-calls

I am trying to write a program that prints an integer, the integer is stored in rax register, I don't know why it only prints the first digit of the integer, in this case it's 3.
The program divides rax by 10 and stores the remainder+48 in the reserved memory to display it later. we repeat this as long as rax is different than 0.

code:

```
section .bss
    integer resb 100

section .text

    global _start
_start:
    mov     rax, 321
    call    _printRAX

    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall

_printRAX:
    mov     rbx, 10
    mov     rcx, integer
    mov     [rcx], rbx

_loop1:
    inc     rcx
    mov     rdx, 0
    div     rbx
    add     rdx, 48
    mov     [rcx], dl

    cmp     rax, 0
    jne     _loop1

_loop2:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, rcx
    mov     rdx, 1
    syscall

    dec     rcx
    cmp     rcx, integer
    jge     _loop2

    ret
```

output:

```
3
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bVDLboMwELzvV/gDaIRpFVW55RdyqlRVkR8rRGQw8loV@XrqByHFgcvi2Z3ZmRVE2EtzfxsE9fNMqHxnB3aQRMDC1w0eW3TMIUnG6xpgHfE4eUhDrbFSGHYlL5yHXE6p09vfWJgTU8XeG55AJYyJ9Tq6IH85f8Hr7LHeYrqrWIboTlEAYKUXq2Sg84KuArZE2TS@Q@enipygZ6wd@WmJrR7Ewsf08KG7dV96C62fIx@fe2u0yUlVPz6TZrXbgAnKJhYzzc4R@etdCogCtOubb@4X/3MQ3GZd3ZVHu7X/PDY5ikMP8/wH)

Comment: Well, what do you think `mov rdx, 1` is doing?

Comment: @Jester the syscall prints 1 byte starting from adress at rcx. at least I think

Comment: That's exactly what it is doing. So of course it will only print a single digit. Because you told it to.

Comment: @Jester But it's a loop and rcx gets decremented every iteration.

Comment: Haha, sorry the scrollbar tricked me, I didn't see you were looping at the bottom too.

Comment: `syscall` destroys `rcx`, you need to save it elsewhere. E.g. `push`/`pop` it. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester I see, can you please tell me what other registers get destroyed by syscall?

Comment: Also `r11` IIRC.

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much sir!